# Codeigniter Routers

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hi I have changed the location of these folder below to new location. But for some reason I can not remember how to change it in the index.php page so can pick new locations up because can not pick up constants I use to be able to do it but can not remember now.

```
application/cache
application/config
application/core
application/helpers
application/hooks
application/libraries
application/logs
application/thirdparty
```

To new Location Below

```
system/engine/cache
system/engine/config
system/engine/core
system/engine/helpers
system/engine/hooks
system/engine/libraries
system/engine/logs
system/engine/thirdparty
```

All now that is left in the application folder is

```
controllers
models
language
views
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you want to move the application folder to a new location. You can change to application folder in the index.php, just search for `$application_folder = 'application';` and change it to `$application_folder = 'system/engine';`. But you also have to move

```
controllers
models
language
views
```

to the new location.

Comment: Only moving these application/cache
application/config
application/core
application/helpers
application/hooks
application/libraries
application/logs
application/thirdparty

Comment: okay, then you can use the hmvc plugin. You change the application folder as described above, and then add the application folder to the modules_locations. There is a good explanation on http://somethingstatic.com/setting-hmvc-codeigniter-2-1/